# Simple Dating App: Security Rules specified to a Path

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to perform some security rules for a simple dating app using firebase (actually a test, so do not expect to much from my data structure). I have the following Database:

```
Female_User (Collection)
........JikoSUJJozEEUJz7gLQq (Document)
        ........Data (Collection)
        ........Likes (Collection)
                ........9SpjkLtbo5fKz1f3doGx (Document)
        ........Unlikes (Collection)
        ........Matches (Collection)
```

The male User is equivalent.

Lets pretend we are the male User `9SpjkLtbo5fKz1f3doGx` liking the female User `JikoSUJJozEEUJz7gLQq`:

The write process in the female's (generally the opposites) `/Matches/{documents}` shall only be allowed when the male ID exists in her `/Likes/{documents}`.

I tried the following security rules with the simulator:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    allow read;
    match /Female_User/{UserID}{
        match /Matches/{MatchIDs}{
            allow write: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/Female_User/$(User_ID)/Likes/$(request.auth.uid));
        }
    }
  }
}
```

The procedure is denied everytime in the simulator. Where is the fault in my exist check? And do I have to specify the female UID, because if we have multiple accounts and 3 females liked the male user, wouldn't the method allow the male writing all the time and to every account beside those he liked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule's wildcard value `UserID` doesn't match its usage in the document path as `User_ID`.  Note the underscore.

Comment: silly me. That was the mistake. I was searching in the wrong direction. Thank you very much